# Puting Gtk.Label in Gtk.TreeView row

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygtk, gtktreeview

I try to put markuped text (potentially containing italic, bold, color) in a `Gtk.TreeView` column, using the following example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


class CellRendererLabelWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Gtk.Label in Gtk.ListStore Example")


        # Creating the ListStore object
        self.liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, Gtk.Label)

        # Making the ListStore Model
        label=Gtk.Label()
        label.set_markup("<b>baz</b> foo")
        self.liststore.append(["bar", label])

        treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.liststore)

        # Preparing the first column only plain text
        renderer_text_0 = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column_text_0 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Text", renderer_text_0, text=0)
        treeview.append_column(column_text_0)

        # Preparing the second column with label
        renderer_text_1 = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column_text_1 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Label", renderer_text_1, text=1)
        treeview.append_column(column_text_1)


        self.add(treeview)


win = CellRendererLabelWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

And I get the following error message:

```
GtkLabelInGtkList.py:43: Warning: unable to set property 'text' of type 'gchararray' from value of type 'GtkLabel'
  win.show_all()
GtkLabelInGtkList.py:44: Warning: unable to set property 'text' of type 'gchararray' from value of type 'GtkLabel'
  Gtk.main()
```

And the following window rendering:

[image: First window render image]

As you see, the “Label” column row is empty when I was expecting something like “**baz** foo”.

As the error message said, Gtk try to find the property `text` in `GtkLabel` and doesn’t find it. So, I replace `text` into `label` to make the line like this `column_text_1 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Label", renderer_text_1, label=1)`. But then I get the following error:

```
(GtkLabelInGtkList.py:10013): Gtk-WARNING **: Cannot connect attribute 'label' for cell renderer class 'GtkCellRendererText' since attribute does not exist
```

So what is the solution to put a `Label` (or other Gtk’s widgets) inside a `TreeView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** put widgets inside a GtkTreeView, only cell renderers.

If you want to show markup inside a tree view column, you can use the [`markup` property](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellRendererText.html#GtkCellRendererText--markup) of `GtkCellRendererText` instead of the `text` property:

```py
self.liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, str)
self.liststore.append(["bar", "<b>baz</b> foo"])

# ...

column_text_0 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Text", renderer_text_0, text=0)
column_text_1 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Markup", renderer_text_1, markup=1)
```